# Delete all files of a folder after every 24 hours in PHP

Tags: php

I searched some related questions but unable to understand them.

I want to delete all the files of folder after every 24 hours but sometimes I get warnings and sometime it works. The folder path is `c:\wamp\www\Jamil`.

Here's the source:

```
<?php
$dir = "Jamil"; // directory name

foreach (scandir($dir) as $item) {
    if ($item == '.' || $item == '..')
        continue;

        if((time() - filemtime($item)) >= 30    && is_file($item)){
        unlink($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$item);
        echo "All files deleted";}
    }   
//rmdir($dir);

?>
```

I copied the code from various sites. Can anyone help? I get this warning:

> Warning: filemtime() [function.filemtime]: stat failed for jamil.html in C:\wamp\www\delete1.php on line 10

Comment: Use Cron for Linux or Sheduled task for Windows. PHP is not intended to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you use php script for this, you still need to somehow schedule it to run. So you could instead schedule the deletion itself using cron or scheduled tasks.
[Here](http://www.pantz.org/software/cron/croninfo.html) is a good reference for crontab.
If you use Windows write yourself a tiny batch script, go to Control Panel, and you get a nice little wizard guiding you trough task scheduling.

PHP is really not the tool for scheduled tasks. It is good if your user needs to do the deletion whenever he/she feels like, but not for scheduled tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function;

```
function wipedir($dir) {
        try{  
            if(is_dir($dir)){
                $mydir = opendir($dir);
                while(false !== ($file = readdir($mydir))) {
                    if($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                        chmod($dir.$file, 0777);
                        if(is_dir($dir.$file)) {
                            chdir('.');
                            destroy($dir.$file.'/');
                            rmdir($dir.$file) or DIE("Unable to delete $dir$file");
                        }else{
                            unlink($dir.$file) or DIE("Unable to delete $dir$file");
                        }
                    }
                }
                closedir($mydir);

                return true;
            }else{return true;}
        }catch (Exception $e){return false;} 
    }
```

So usage would be

```
$dir = 'Jamil';
wipedir($dir);
```

This should be placed in a file run by crontab etc at the specified interval.

Comment: just remove the rmdir no need to destroy it and then to recreate it :)

Comment: But where you have specified the time that it should delete files after 24 hours??

Comment: As I said in the last line @user2290749, you should run it via cron tab. Can usually be done via cPanel: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron - http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/cpanel/cron_jobs.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
is_file($item)
```

try

```
 if(is_dir($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$item) && $item != ".." && $item != ".")
```